# What are the implications if a projection is zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have the following two projections that are zero:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty a(x, y) dy = \int_{-\infty}^\infty y a(x,y) dy = 0$$
Is there anything that can be said about $a(x,y)$? What family of functions satisfy the projections above?

Comment: It's just a rewording, but those are the functions orthogonal to all affine-linear functions ...

Comment: first thing to be said: $x$ does not play any role. second thing: $0=\int a(y)\mathrm{d}y$ implies $\int a^+(y)\mathrm{d_y}=\int a^-(y)\mathrm{d}y<\infty$, third thing: for $\int ya(y)\mathrm{d}y$ to exist $a$ has to drop at least superlinearly for $y\rightarrow +-\infty$ I would guess, might well be you even need quadratically.